Building Docker Image in Azure - Using Private Github Repos as Pip Dependencies
I currently have multiple Dockerized APIs hosted by Azure. The code and CI for all of these is in Github, and pip is used for package management. To remove some duplicative code, certain common modules were broken out into their own repos, and included in requirements.txt in the format git+ssh://git@github.com/my-org/my_repo.git. Locally, this works perfectly fine. I am able to bring in the ssh as a secret and can perform all docker compose actions with no options.
Building the image in Azure has proven to be much more complicated.
I run a github action with the following workflow:
name: API Build

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      ENV:
        required: true
        type: string
      DOCKERFILE:
        required: true
        type: string
      IMAGE_TAG:
        required: true
        type: string
    secrets:
      ACR_REGISTRY:
        required: true
      ACR_USERNAME:
        required: true
      ACR_PASSWORD:
        required: true

jobs:
  build:
    name: API Build
    runs-on: "ubuntu-latest"

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Docker Build
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3

      - name: Log in to container registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          registry: ${{ secrets.ACR_REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ secrets.ACR_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.ACR_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Build and push container image to registry
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v6
        with:
          push: true
          context: .
          tags: "${{ secrets.ACR_REGISTRY }}/${{ inputs.IMAGE_TAG }}"
          file: "${{ inputs.DOCKERFILE }}"
          build-args: |
            ENVIRONMENT=${{ inputs.ENV }}
          secrets: |
            "github_token=${{ secrets.EXT_LIB_TOKEN }}"


and a dockerfile where I set up the python environment (for which I change the urls so that pip includes the dependencies as https with a PAT) and start the function loop:
FROM python:3.10

# Install Python Requirements
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN mkdir -p /my-proj
WORKDIR /my-proj
COPY ./requirements.txt /my-proj/requirements.txt

# Inject the new URLs into the requirements.txt file
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=github_token sed -i.bak "s|git+ssh://git@github.com/|git+https://$(cat /run/secrets/github_token)@github.com/|g" /my-proj/requirements.txt && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r /my-proj/requirements.txt

# Initialize the app
COPY . /my-proj/
EXPOSE 8500
CMD ["./docker/api/startup.sh"]

It seems clear to me that Azure may not support secrets in docker.
TL;DR Has anybody found a reliable way to pull private repos when building a docker image for Azure?
Thank you very much in advance.
